# Certificate store/caching problem

Tags: firefox, security, certificates

I have been having a strange issue with my machine lately. When I try to load up an https encrypted site, it rarely gives an `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`. What is odd is that this happens on very well maintained sites (e.g., Google) and if I refresh the page it uses the proper certificate.

So far I have only noticed it in firefox, but that is also the only browser I use frequently. Another interesting thing is that it is always the same certificate for the same domains.

[image: What firefox tells me.]
[image: Details.]

If anyone needs more details please let me know.

Comment: There are a few possibilities. Firefox could be buggy and connecting to the wrong server. Your DNS server could be buggy and returning the IP address of `bing.com` sometimes when you ask for `www.google.com`. A proxy server you use is buggy and connecting to the wrong server.

Comment: My ISP has this annoying behaviour of sometimes randomly redirecting requests to their email webpage. When that happens with an HTTPS site, I get this error.